# Stop action when button is released

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 app that controls Lego Mindstorms I have a `Button` with `UIElement.Hold Event` that triggers method `runMotor()` When I release the `Button` motor keeps on going but I would like it to stop. Method for  stopping is `stopMotor()`, I've already tried to assign it to `KeyUp Event` but it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to call `stopMotor()` in [ManupulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event. Note that `ManipulationCompleted` event will get invoked after any gesture manipulation including [Tap, Double Tap, Hold, and other gesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Take that into account. If application scenario is still simple, checking if motor already running before calling `stopMotor` in `ManipulationCompleted` event handler maybe enough :

```
private void MyButton_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(isMotorRunning) stopMotor();
}
```